# How to get minimum date from date fields except null values?

Tags: mysql, sql

My datatable is likes follows,

```
ID | Date1      | Date2      | Date3
--------------------------------------- 
1  | 2017-09-12 | null       | 2017-10-11 
2  | null       | 2017-09-21 | null 
3  | 2017-11-01 | null       | null 
4  | 2017-08-01 | 2017-09-22 | 2017-09-23
```

I want to get minimum date for each rows from **Date1,Date2 and Date3**

I tried it from

```
select LEAST(IFNULL(Date1,'9999-12-31'),IFNULL(Date2,'9999-12-31'),IFNULL(Date3,'9999-12-31'))
```

this way, It works, But I want to know is this the BEST way to ignore the null values when I want to get minimum date from multiple dates.

Comment: Just guessing here: You tagged the question with MySQL and Oracle. I don't know MySQL, but I know some Oracle, and it has no IFNULL function. If what you tried worked, then it's not Oracle. So I will remove the `oracle` tag. In the future, please pay attention to the tags (SO attaches its guesses automatically, which are almost always wrong.)

Comment: @mathguy My bad, Thanks for reply

Comment: Fix your schema. Any time you find yourself with enumerated columns (above 2, anyway), alarm bells should start ringing